# Why shouldn't XML comments contain hidden commands?

Tags: java, xml, xsd, xml-parsing, xml-comments

I'm reading ***Core Java*** vol. 2 by Cay Horstmann, and in the chapter about XML where he talks about XML comments he says:

> Comments should only be information for human readers. They should
>   never contain hidden commands; use processing instructions for
>   commands.

What does he mean by *hidden commands*, why can't I use them in XML comments and and how do I use processing instructions for them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML comments shouldn't contain out-of-band (*hidden*) data or commands because the purpose of XML is to communicate information within a mutually agreed upon framework.

Neither the rules of well-formedness that define the basis of XML itself nor the common XML schema languages that define further constraints of an XML document's vocabulary and grammar have a means to define the contents of a comment beyond that of basic text.  This is by design and mirrors similar design decisions regarding comments in many programming languages.

Instead of adding flags, or worse, a micro-language within XML comments, surface data as XML elements and attributes, and surface commands as processing instructions so that the entire existing ecosystem of parsers, schemas, validators, and established standards may be leveraged in reading and writing the data.

Answer (score 0):

Some characters have a different meaning in XML.

If you place a character like "<" inside an XML element, it will generate an error because the parser interprets it as the start of a new element.

This will generate an XML error because the parser will look for a matching closing tab:
salary < 1000 
(This can cause major problems once the application goes live)

When you use commands inside of a comment, it could sometimes inevitably cause parsing errors such as above. Being a hidden command inside of a comment, it will become difficult to find the root cause of parsing issues as we may not look inside the comment. Hence it is better to avoid adding hidden commands inside of comments.

Answer (score 0):

Because of these two reasons:

1. To reduce misinterpretations or possible mistakes, even comments should not include commands that are likely to be considered an executable statement. XML scripts are for transferring data and patterns in them should be defined completely clear.
2. It is for secure programming. To completely prevent someone from running the files, XML files should never contain hidden commands. By this you prevent abuse of code. By hidden commands someone may copy the files somewhere else to run them, or even use the command.